# Responsive layout for text and button

Tags: html, css

How to make the text and button inside container responsive? I try add in @ media only my table responsive but no for button and text. Here is my html and css code

```
<p>Welcome to LinkSphere</p>
<div id="home-button">
<a class="button1" href="#">Fill Form</a>
<a class="button1" href="#">View Results</a>
<a class="button1" href="#">Admin Site</a>
</div>

CSS:
p{
text-align:center;
font-size:25px;
line-height: 150%;
margin:-50px 80px 0;
}
/*Home table button*/
#home-button{
text-align: center;
margin: 100px 60px 0 0!important;
}
.button1 {
display: inline;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 20px;
width: 12em;
padding: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFFFFF; /*words*/
background: #0080FF;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button1:hover { /*after pointing*/
cursor: pointer;
background: #00407F;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tidy up your question:

What do you mean in the second sentence?
Can you indent your code and maybe provide the markup?

Answer (score 1):

Your `display: inline` declaration is why your button is not filling in the full width of your content.

If you change it to `display: block` then your button will then grow to fill the content area where it's being wrapped in.